# error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
import React, { document } from "react";
import "./LoginandRegister.css";

function LoginandRegister() {
  const signUpButton = document.getElementById("signUp");
  const signInButton = document.getElementById("signIn");
  const container = document.getElementById("container");

  signUpButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active")
  );
  signInButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active")
  );
```

Comment: Hey Arnon, welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to provide some context to your code and don't just paste in your code as is. Also, tell what you have already tried to solve this problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: not sure why you want (or must use) getElementbyId, but you should use "useRef", I think it is better for perfermance.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to handle button interaction in React, but using `getElementById` and attaching event listeners is not considered normal/good practice. You should also make sure to provide any css classes to the `className` prop, instead of using `classList.add(...)`, assuming that `signUp`, `signIn`, and `container` are all being rendered as React components or JSX.

Take a look at [Handling Events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for some inspiration on how to go about handling button clicks.

Also, importing `document` from the react package overrides the default document object you can use to attach event listeners. So I'd guess that it would work if you removed the import, so it just said `import React from 'react'`. Though I believe it's still not a proper solution and you should definitely take a look at the React documentation.

Comment: I want to use this method I want to find a solution to it.

Comment: Your code is going to be anti-pattern and I'd strongly advise against it, but the solution would likely be to change the React import as I mentioned.